# Logging behavior of Codeigniter | show_404()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use a controller to do some custom uri routing for pages, it's currently working great.

Here is a stripped down version of the controller which uses PHPTAL as it's template engine.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->tal->display('index');
}

public function view($url)
{       
    $this->loadView($url);
}   

private function loadView($url) 
{

   if (file_exists(ROOTPATH . 'webroot/' . $url . '/index.html')) 
   {
       $this->tal->display($url . '/index');
   } 
   else 
   {  
       show_404();
   }
}
```

## The problem

I recently noticed that the following error was appearing in my logs each time the page controller was accessed:

`ERROR - 2013-02-06 10:58:23 --> 404 Page Not Found -->`

I found this strange as the page displays as expected and there is definitely no 404 header and the network panel shoes no 404 status.

I finally narrowed this down to the `show_404()` helper method being called in the `loadView()` method. Removing that line stops the errors from appearing in the log file altogether.

This §show_404()§ should only be executed if the view file cannot be found, in which case it should show the 404 error page, which it does. However the logging part of the method appears to be being executed on every call to the page controller, regardless of whether the `loadView()` method is called or not.

## Example

I access the `index()` view in the browser, everything appears to work fine, the correct view file is loaded, there are no errors. However a 404 error message is logged from the `loadView()` method. The `loadView()` method isn't even being called from the `index()` method, yet the existence of its output in the log files seems to indicate that it is being executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default behaviour of `show_404` is to [insert a log entry when its called](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Common.php#L381-392). There's a second optional parameter to disable it, so if you just want to show the 404 page without logging it call it like this:

```php
show_404('', false);
```

The first parameter is the string that would be appended after the `-->` in the logs, so you can leave that empty too.

#### As for why the `_loadView` function might be get called:

If you are using urls without the `index.php` in them (empty `$config['index_page']`) then every static asset (image, js, css, etc.) that the webserver server can't find (depends on concrete rewrite rules) will be passed to the php script and probably generate a 404 error there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am removing the index.php. But I still don't understand why `_loadView()` (or any other function for that matter) would be getting called in the index view where there is no reference to it? 

Also if _loadView is getting called, why then does the show_404 only log the error and not redirect to the errors/error_404.html page?

Comment: `show_404()` by default wont redirect a request just show the error page. You would only see this if the "original" request got into that route. Try checking the net panel in firebug or network panel in chrome webtools to see if anyting gets a 404 response there. You could try to insert a backtrace next to the `show_404` and log it somewhere too to see where did the call come from.

Comment: There are no 404 responses in my network panel. If I remove the show_404() from my code, I don't get any 404 errors logged. If i insert a backtrace next to the show_404() it never gets executed, nor does any other code I insert (as it should be). I.E. - If i add a `echo 'error';die();` It is completely ignored, and the page loads the template/view (as it should do). However if I do a call to `show_404();` or `log_message('error', 'This is an error');`, they appear to be executed despite being functions that haven't been called as their messages are logged to the log files.

Comment: Well, somehow the logging gets invoked. Since ["select” Isn’t Broken](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips) I would try moving the backtrace/debug logging stuff into the core `log_message()` function until something useful surfaces itself.

Comment: Not sure I understand why/how it was occurring and it's relationship to the show_404() call in my controller. But it appears to have been caused by my misspelling of the href attribute for the favicon.icn link tag. Your answer helped a lot!

Comment: Probably have no relationship, the CI routing process have like 10 places where it calls `show_404()` well before involving any of your controller code (in cases when it can't find a controller for example).

Comment: I would of assumed so, but still the errors were not logged if I removed the controllers show_404() function. Anyway, you were right on the mark!